# Create GRID GUI tableusing Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, grid

I've never worked with .NET and C# but my user story is about it.
I have to create a table using GRID. As far as I know, I'm using Winform. I inserted a table into my page from the toolbox, but it is not responsive when I extend or reduce the page.

Do you have some links related to my issue (Create a table with grid) or some explanations?
Because what I've found do not suit me.

I do not even know what GRID means, is that about the responsive design of table's columns/raws?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Grid view from Toolbox. It's look like a table.

Comment: see the article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/211551/A-Simple-way-for-Paging-in-DataGridView-in-WinForm